# GCC Linker: Does subsequent -L options override previous -L settings

Tags: gcc, ld

I am having trouble cross compiling the wpa-supplicant code with errors stating that `libnl.so.2` is not found.

I have checked and the `libnl.so`, `libnl.so.2` and `libnl.so.2.0.0` are all present in the /lib directory.

I added the `-v` option to get verbatim output and I could see multiple `-L` options passed to the linker. All of the `-L` paths preceed the object file lists.

My question is thus: 
**Does subsequent `-L` options override previous `-L` options?**

I can post the verbatim commandline, but there are quite a lot of object files loaded. However, just ask if it is needed to answer this question.

Thanks in advance for the help.
Ivor

Comment: -L options are chained to the library search path (so no override).

Comment: run `file libnl.so` and make sure that the files are the same architecture you're compiling for and also make sure that the /lib directory is included in your -L options... and yeah, what oakad said.